# Creating service account in AD

Tags: active-directory

I am creating a Service account for a domain in the AD. The user is created under Managed Service Accounts. But from any server, when the user is used to start a service, I get a logon failure.

What is the rigt procedure to create a Service user on AD with only logon as a service right?

What groups should the user belong to, to have logon as a service right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any AD user account can be a service account. It's how it's used that makes it a service account.

The "Log on as a service" privilege is a Group Policy setting that must be granted on each computer where it is needed. You can either do this in a Group Policy on the domain, or on the computer itself by running "gpedit.msc". You'll find "Log on as a service" under:

Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/log-on-as-a-service

Comment: I created the user but I am not able to create the group policy on the domain controller. When i am searching for `SeServiceLogonRight` no group is found in the system.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to create a group policy on the domain. You can just modify the group policy directly on the computer using the instructions in my answer.

Comment: I added group policy because i have multiple servers that needs to be changed.